# Is it possible to build Wix 4 using devenv without Wix or the HeatWave extension installed?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, devenv, wix4

I have a Wix setup project that was recently converted from Wix 3 to Wix 4. I installed the HeatWave extension to perform the conversion and I'm able to build with it installed in Visual Studio 2022. However, my company uses `nuget restore` and `devenv` for builds. When the build runs without HeatWave, there's an error for the `.wixproj` that says, "The application for the project is not installed" even though I have the `WixToolset.Heat` in my `.wixproj` as a package reference.

I read the [Integrating WiX Projects Into Daily Builds](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/msbuild/daily_builds/) article and that's what we were using previously with Wix 3, so I was hoping to achieve something similar with Wix 4 where the HeatWave extension doesn't have to be installed and everything can process using the NuGet packages. If I don't have the HeatWave extension installed, Visual Studio doesn't recognize the `.wixproj` at all. Once I add it back, it appears to build just fine as long as it targets x86.

Is there a way to build Wix 4 using `nuget restore` and `devenv`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was not the goal that building `.wixprojs` would require HeatWave to be installed. But I've not seen anyone actually using `devenv` to do builds in CI/CD systems. That's such a heavyweight way to build .sln files.

Generally, CI/CD is expected to be running `msbuild` or `dotnet build`. Both of those can build a .sln file and all the project references in it.

So, I'd say you are in a situation we never tested when using WiX. I'm glad HeatWave happens to just work (because I know we didn't test it at FireGiant :smile:).

Comment: Can Wix 4 be downloaded as a standalone application and included in the solution the way it was in Wix 3 for daily builds, as described at the following link: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/msbuild/daily_builds/?

Comment: @user2063351 that's a better question than a comment.

Comment: I thought it was a relevant, clarifying question to ask based on your response and my inclusion of the same link in my original question. I appreciate your original response either way, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, you cannot build `.wixproj` without HeatWave if you are using `devenv`. However, nothing is stopping you from making the extension a `.csproj` since it's SDK based now, which is what I personally do. WiX4 also allows you to build from the command line very easily with `dotnet build`.

So your two courses of action:

1. Rename extension to `.csproj` and use `devenv`. Cons: You lose all HeatWave integration but this doesn't matter if you know what you're doing.
2. Use `dotnet build` to build the SDK based project.

Comment: When I build with VS2019 (16.11.26) devenv, I'm getting this error message: `The project file cannot be opened by the project system, because it is missing some critical imports or the referenced SDK cannot be found.`

I have the following in the .csproj file:
`<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.2">`
`<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.UI.wixext" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Heat" Version="4.0.2" />
 </ItemGroup>`

The build process uses `nuget.exe restore` first. Any idea why the SDKs aren't being loaded using the .csproj approach?